# My android service causes the app to crash

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to call a method of another class but this causes my app to crash.

This is what I'm doing to run it on boot

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          MyApp test = new MyApp();
          test.run_service();
   }
}
```

I've commented out all the lines from run_service() to find out what the cause is, and it's this line

```
SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
```

It works fine if I call it from within that class (when the application is the foreground), so why can't I call it from inside onReceieve?

Updated to add notification code:

```
CharSequence title = "MyApp";
CharSequence message = "Hello World";

NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "Hi!", System.currentTimeMillis());

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MyApp.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
n.setLatestEventInfo(MyApp.this, title, message, pendingIntent);
nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, n);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way
call this way

```
test.run_service(context);
```

your run method

```
void run_service(Context context){
     SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
}
```

Comment: Okay that fixed it. But this function also uses the notification service. How do I make that use this context as well?

Comment: you can use the context object like context.getSystemSerive(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) and in Intent/PendingIntent use context instead of "this"

Comment: It's still crashing :/

I've updated the question with the new code.

Comment: I tried that, but then the app doesn't build anymore saying cannot find symbol (symbol: variable context)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I was trying MyApp.context.. I got it working now. Thanks :)